# JSX add attribute to array of different objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a page with a bunch of sub-pages:

```js
render(){
  let elements = [<Apple>,<Orange>,<Pear>];
  return <div>
    {Elements}
  </div>
}
```

I want to give each of these elements the same property, e.g. color:

```js
render(){
  let elements = [<Apple>,<Orange>,<Pear>];
  elements.forEach(i=>i.setAttribute('color','blue')); //???
  return <div>
    {Elements}
  </div>
}
```

So that it would be equivalent to:

```js
render(){
  return <div>
    <Apple color='blue'/>
    <Orange color='blue'/>
    <Pear color='blue'/>
  </div>
}
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your `elements` to

```js
let elements = [Apple, Orange, Pear];
```

then use array [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to pass a common `prop`.

```js
render() {
  let elements = [Apple, Orange, Pear];
  const elementsWithColorBlue = elements.map((Element) => (
    <Element color="blue" />
  ));
  
  return <div>{elementsWithColorBlue}</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way of writing than the answer above would be as below

```js
render(){
  return (
    <div>
      {[Apple, Orange, Pear].map(Element => <Element color="blue" />)}
    </div>
  )
}
```